# Bypassing/ignoring corrupt Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have to loop through Excel files stored in a folder and process them using VBA. I want to only process those Excel files that open without any questions being asked (questions like unreadable content, corrupted file, unknown source etc).

Is there some way to do this? I have tried On Error go to Label, but the problem still persists with some files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds weird.  You didn't post any sample code, but you can try it like this.

```
Sub t()

Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False

On Error Resume Next
'other code here
On Error GoTo 0

Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True

End Sub
```

Normally, 'On Error Resume Next' is not recommended, because it will hide all kinds of errors from your view, which can be quite helpful for debugging issues, but in this case it may be appropriate.